# Divine Blessings and Antimagic field

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, divine, antimagic-field

Would a deity's [*divine blessing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm) be affected by [*antimagic field*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm)? Would other types of divine blessings? Would different types of blessings be affected differently by an antimagic field?

Comment: *Curiosity:* Did this come up in play or are you working toward a trick?

Comment: Trick. I'm trying to find the boundaries between what deity given effects persist in an antimagic field and which don't, specifically for vow of poverty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, salient divine abilities are not affected by antimagic fields.**

In the general rules about divine abilities at the top of your linked page is the following:

> **Salient Divine Abilities and Antimagic**
>   A salient divine ability functions normally within an antimagic field, and is never subject to spell resistance.

Comment: So could this be extrapolated to divine blessings (not the specific ability) in general? Oh, I'm just going to come out and say it: I want the extraordinary abilities from my deity-given vow of poverty to not be suppressed in an antimagic field, and I'm wondering if the fact that it was given  to me by my deity gives me a RAW loophole.

Comment: @Cellheim You already asked that question; asking it again under a different guise is an excellent way to spoil people’s interest in volunteering their time to help you. And, no matter how many times you ask it, the answer will still be no.

Comment: @KRyan I know but it looked like you were wrong and the specific ability divine blessing lasts in a antimagic field, so why not divine blessings in general? I just wasn't sure if the previous thread was considered closed or something since it had been so long. That's why I didn't just post a new comment there. Apologies if that would have been the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @Cellheim No, questions don’t age out here; we try to keep one question for each, well, question. If you find answers to your questions aren’t quite getting at the details you want, editing is the answer. If you just want more attention on the question, a bounty is the solution. Duplicate questions are bad; this one isn’t quite but it is a rather trivial question on its face and the real question you meant to ask would be. Please see the [tour] for more about how we work here.

Comment: @KRyan should I delete it and go back to the first question?

Comment: No real harm in having the question even if it is fairly trivial, in my opinion. But answers about any other form of divine boon’s reaction to *antimagic field* should happen in their own questions (your other one, for Vow of Poverty and really, for any exalted feats at the very least).